# Object detection(Tensorflow) Slow processing video

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am using the Tensorflow Object detection API.
The problem is that I intend to analyze a video but the processing is too slow, and I hardly use the GPU or the CPU (I use tensorflow-gpu)
When the video is played next to the detection of objects it does not reach 30 fps, it is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be lower in your GPU capacity.So Please try to increase your GPU in hardware level and there was a known issue same like this.Please refer https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3270 You can have more answers on it.